# Rails. Rewrite clearance controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, clearance

I try add js in clearance controllers. Users-controllers rewrite ok, but sessions and passwords controllers not work.

user_controller (work):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      respond_to :js
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
        :email,
        :password,
    )
  end
end
```

sessions_controller (not work):

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController    
  def new
      respond_to :js
  end

  def create
    respond_to :js

    @user = authenticate(params)

    sign_in(@user) do |status|
        if status.success?
            #redirect_back_or url_after_create
        else
            respond_to :js
        end
    end
  end
end
```

sessions/new.html.slim :

```
= form_for :session, html: {id: 'new_session', class: 'new_session'}, url: session_path, remote: true do |form|

  = form.label :email
  = form.text_field :email

  = form.label :password 
  = form.password_field :password 

  = form.submit "Log in"
```

sessions/create.js.erb

```
$(".stuff").prepend("<div>It worked!</div>")
```

my routes:

```
                 sign_in GET    /sign_in(.:format)                              clearance/sessions#new
                 session GET    /session(.:format)                              clearance/sessions#new
                sign_out DELETE /sign_out(.:format)                             clearance/sessions#destroy
                 sign_up GET    /sign_up(.:format)                              clearance/users#new
               passwords POST   /passwords(.:format)                            clearance/passwords#create
            new_password GET    /passwords/new(.:format)                        clearance/passwords#new
           session_index POST   /session(.:format)                              clearance/sessions#create
     user_password_index POST   /users/:user_id/password(.:format)              clearance/passwords#create
      edit_user_password GET    /users/:user_id/password/:id/edit(.:format)     clearance/passwords#edit
           user_password PATCH  /users/:user_id/password/:id(.:format)          clearance/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/password/:id(.:format)          clearance/passwords#update
                   users POST   /users(.:format)                                users#create
```

How fix it?

Comment: How to fix what exactly? What is not working for you?

Comment: For example, I not see flash-message "Passwords new" on password reset page passwords/new. I cant rewrite clearance controllers. If I can add this massage, I can add js in controller.

Comment: What is the pertinet output of `rake routes`. Have you updated the routes to point to your new controller?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I find bug. It was in views. Controller work fine.

Comment: I was wrong. The question is still relevant. Add my routes and passwords/create.js.erb

Comment: Can you add the sessions controller and the way you're interacting with those controllers?, I mean the views.

Comment: add sessions controller and sesions views